# Adding fixed seed nodes as DNS doesn't seem to be available

Tags: bitcoind, regtest, seed

I am pretty new to bitcoin and I am trying to create a private blockchain by using `bitcoind -regtest -daemon`. But the executable stops, giving this message:

```
"Adding fixed seed nodes as DNS doesn't seem to be available"
```

Could anyone help me out with this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the executable stops after giving that message, or that it  doesn't give that message anymore? The latter is to be expected, since you don't have any DNS seeds.

Comment: Yes executable freezes giving the above message. Do I have to add dns seeds manually ? If yes how do I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

The message means that no DNS seeds were found (which is normal, as regtest has no DNS seeds), and thus that it will fall back to its builtin list of fixed seed nodes (which regtest has 0 of).

In other words, the message is harmless and the artifact of DNS/seed logic that doesn't really apply to regtest.

Regtest is a private network for testing, so you don't want it to connect to any specific other node by default. If you want it to connect to others, use -connect, -addnode, -listen, etc.

I suspect it's not actually frozen, just not doing anything because it has no connections. In that case, it would still accept RPC commands fine.